# Why some of HDFS reads are so slow, when all the data is cached in off-heap?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, libhdfs

I'm doing performance test for HDFS. I'm using HDFS C++ API. I notice that most of the reads take up to 5 microseconds. But some of reads take 500-800 microseconds. What could be the reason, considering all the data is in OS cache? No disk access should be occur.

Comment: What do you mean all the data is in OS cache?

Comment: I've added CachePool, and added all the data to it. It's stored in off-heap, which is managed by OS. I can see from /proc/meminfo that it's in OS cache.